# Imagemagick: How to center a picture on a transparent canvas

Tags: fonts, imagemagick, image-manipulation, image-conversion

I am using ImageMagick to export glyphs from a font.
However, some of these glyphs are smaller than others, and end up not being in the center of the image as a result of that.
I am looking for a way to take a created image and center it on a transparent canvas. I am guessing this means that first the image should be cropped to remove all transparent regions around it, but I am not sure about that.

The ImageMagick command I'm using right now is:

```
convert -size 32x32 canvas:none -channel RGBA -font Fontname -pointsize 32 -fill white -gravity center -draw text 0,0 'a' ./image_cache/a.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`-trim`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#trim) to remove extra padding from the glyph, and [`-extent`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#trim) to grow the image back to original size.

```
convert -size 32x32 -background pink \
        -font Fontname -pointsize 32 -fill white \
        label:a -trim -gravity center -extent 32x32 \
        ./image_cache/a.png
```

[image: How to center a picture on a transparent canvas]